# When I type a number in a textbox the number inside <p> should multiply with the number typed inside the textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my shopping cart page, products are displayed like this in my div box:

[image]

Products get generated and displayed in the shopping cart that the user has added.

The shopping cart page can contain any number of products.

When a user types a number inside the textbox, and then clicks on the update button, the number should multiply with the price taken from the `<p class="price2"></p>` and replace it with the new total amount inside `<p class="price2"></p>`.

Let's say a user types "3" inside the textbox and then presses the button. Then it should be
`"3 * 699 = 2097"` and the `2097` should replace the `699` so it says "`total: 2097"`.

The hard part for me to understand is that this should happen on a specific product div box, so other products aren't affected. With that I mean that I can't use a class or id to get the text from a `<p>`, I need to use parent? Because every product has a `<p class="price2">` and I dont want to change all the product prices.

I would appreciate if someone could help me

[Here is my jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/muKty/8/)

Also here is another jquery that I'm using on the same update button that grabs all the prices and sums them up.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.update').click(function () {
            var total = 0;
            $("span.price2").each(function (i) {
                total += parseFloat($(this).text(), 10);
            });

            $("#total2").html(total);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the keypress event, seems more pretty that having to click.

```
<span class="section">
  <p class="price">699.50</p>
  <input class="qtty" type="text">
  <span class="result">699.50</span>
</span>

<span class="section">
  <span class="price">1234</span>
  <input class="qtty" type="text">
  <span class="result">1234</span>
</span>
```

​

```js
$('.qtty').keypress(function() {
  price = $(this).parent().find('.price').html()
  qtty = $(this).parent().find('.qtty').val()
  result = price * qtty
  $(this).parent().find('.result').html(result)
});​
```

Just a suggestion. Edit: http://jsfiddle.net/qU7ZG/ that's better.

Comment: that seems very cool!!!! but the problem is that I cant use ID beacuse imagen I have 8 products up or maby 6 its generated by amount of added products. I cant use ID I need to use parent or something

Comment: if you check my html in my jsfiddle, it can be like 5-6 of them or maby 3 of them somehow if I type a number in the textbox the <p> that gets the result need to be indicated by being inside the same div box or something

Comment: Hmm can we enter a chat room I think its just a small detail missing in my code

Answer (score 0):

Use the context parameter to the jQuery selector to find the class member within a particular DIV:

```
var total = 0;
$(".produktinfo2").each(function () {
    var that = $(this);
    var subtotal = parseFloat($(".quantity", that).text()) * parseFloat($(".price", that).text());
    $(".price2", that).text(subtotal);
    total += subtotal;
});
$("#total2").text(total);
```